# Sphinx Geo Searches

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using Ruby on Rails and the Thinking-Sphinx Gem with Sphinx as the search program.  I would like to have a bing map where users can draw sales boundries (just a square) and have Sphinx return all customers within the drawn squares.  Is this possible?  I always see Sphinx do radius queries, but nothing inside of a 4 or 5 point box.

I mentioned Rails and THinking-Sphinx just to let you guys know what I was using, although this is more of a Sphinx question than anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, pretty certain Sphinx doesn't support searching within boxes, just radius queries.

Answer (score 2):

Your latitude and longitude values are available as filterable fields/attributes (if you configure sphinx in correct way).

You can set up a "FilterFloatRange" to limit your results to be within the required bounds.
Please note that lat/lon values need to be stored as radiant values.